# Find the optimal frame constants A and B for the frame of $\mathbb{R}^3$: $\mathscr{B}=\{ (1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1), (0,0,1), (1,1,-1) \}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Find the optimal frame constants A and B for the frame of $\mathbb{R}^3$
$$\mathscr{B}=\{ (1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1), (0,0,1), (1,1,-1) \}$$

I am not too comfortable with [frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_a_vector_space) so I need some help.

Comment: What is a frame? Is this a frame as in a linearly dependent spanning set?

Comment: Yes and I find that the first three vectors are independently from each other. Why because $ v_5+v_4=v_2$ and $ v_3-v_4=v_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_1,...,f_l$ is a frame, then
$\sum_k (\langle x, f_k \rangle )^2 = \langle Fx, Fx \rangle = \langle x, F^TFx \rangle$, where
$F = \begin{bmatrix} f_1^T \\
\vdots \\ f_l^T\end{bmatrix}$. We see that $F$ is symmetric, hence
$\lambda_\min \|x\|^2 \le \langle x, F^TFx \rangle \le \lambda_\max \|x\|^2$,
where the $\lambda$s are the $\min$ and $\max$ eigenvalues of $F^T F$.

Comment: Ok I understand the theory I just don't understand the application

Comment: Compute the matrix $F^F$ and then compute the eigenvalues. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes. What is $F^F$?

Comment: I meant $F^T F$.

Comment: then the smallest eigenvalue is A and the largest is B?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok so computing the eigenvalues of the 5 x 5 matrix is turning out to be tedious. Can I do it of simply the linearly independent vector?

Comment: It should be a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Specifically, it is $F^TF = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$, so the eigenvalues are straightforward to compute exactly.

Comment: Oh ok. Perfect. I switched my matrices